# Android HTTP app working on emulator, not properly on my phone(s)

Tags: android-emulator, httpclient, android, cookiestore

I have been struggling with android for the last few weeks and got myself a first working app... on my emulator only unfortunately. I really hope someone can help me out to get it working on my android device(s). Emulator runs v2.2, my devices 2.3+.

I have a singleton 'websiteservice'-class that's beeing created by a class which extends 'Application'. The websiteservice-class creates 1 threadsafeconnection-manager, and contains a 'CookieStore'. Each HTTPGet/Post creates a new HTTPClient, with the threadsafeconn.manager attached to it. Everytime I do a post or get, I try to attach the cookies if available. The cookies are once - and only - set when logging in to the secured part of the website. Together with EntitityUtils.ToString and Jsoup, I parse each HTML result of my 'secured' website part. On logging on, I create a sqllite table in android, in which I store only 1 simple record, the user that logged on.

When I run this on my emulator, everything runs just as I'd like it to be, but on my device, something seems to go terribly wrong. I attached the debugger to my phone. The logging in seems to go just fine, and the cookies are being set. The sqllite bit probably goes fine too, as I don't seem to get errors. Upon loading the profile-page, I can see that the HTTPGet-action get's the cookies attached of the CookieStore, but the HTML-result/doc I receive, is 95% of the times the login-page.

I say 95%, because I did get to my profile-page once or twice on my rooted Desire HD, but on another Desire HD I didn't, and on my Sensation XE neither. The times I did get the profile-page loaded (a custom listbox with a hashmap as input), I couldn't start any action. They aborted right away, and probably they had the same issue (getting login-page as result).

Are there any permissions I forgot, is there anything I should check, or do you have any idea what it could be? I'm really confused right now.

**Small update**
I just rebooted my phone. When I start the program, the first time I log on, my profile page gets loaded. My 'detail' action seems to work. This action does not connect to the internet or so, it simply displays information I stored in a class. My other 2 actions (copy and delete) don't work (I probably get the 'login page' as a result). When I turn my screen (orientation changes), the page 'restarts' and it's trying to load the profile page again. The listbox is cleared, and I don't get my profile page (which is a list of adverts) back.

**Update 2 - 08-03**
My manifest file only contains the internet-permission, apart from the registration of my activities. A small 'weird' extra. It seems my 'back-up' code is nearly equal to my code posted here. Each time it does seem to attach my cookies, but still it doesn't do anything with it :(. Also, I was playing around a bit yesterday with my phone, I changed orentiation a few times (which reloads the activity automatically), and suddenly, I once or twice had my profile in front. I couldn't do any action on it, but my class containing information was accessable and filled. PS. Just now 8.15 AM my time, I again could load my profile after switching orientation 4-5 times.

**Update 08-03-2012**
I have been puzzling and tried lots of things in the evening, and now I even got my emulator-version back to square 1. Got a backup, so np, but I think I'm not using my http-client properly. I removed all previous code, here's my current code I use for my 'websiteservice', and my 'Webclient' which I instantiate on each get/post, by simply attaching the connectionmanager.

```
private static WebsiteService instance;

    ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager;
    HttpContext localContext;
    CookieStore cookies;
    public String returnCode = "";
    public HttpPost httpPost = null;
    public HttpGet httpGet = null;

    public static WebsiteService getInstance()
    {
        // Return the instance
        return instance;
    }

    private WebsiteService()
    {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
        manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,mgr.getSchemeRegistry());
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        cookies = new BasicCookieStore();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookies);
    }

    public static void initInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new WebsiteService();
    }

    public WebsiteClient postPage(String url, List<NameValuePair> nvps)
    {
        return postPage(url, nvps, true);
    }

    public WebsiteClient getPage(String url) {

        WebsiteClient client = new WebsiteClient(manager);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = client.httpClient;

        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
        //HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpClient.getParams(), "CP1250");

        if(cookies != null)
            httpClient.setCookieStore(cookies);

        httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            client.response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,localContext);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPService : ClientProtocolException : "+e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPService : IOException : "+e);
            return null;
        }

        //cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore();
        return client;
    }


    public WebsiteClient postPage(String url, List<NameValuePair> nvps, boolean autoRedirect) {

        WebsiteClient client = new WebsiteClient(manager);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = client.httpClient;
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

        if(cookies != null)
            httpClient.setCookieStore(cookies);

        if(!autoRedirect)
        {
            HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
            HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
        }

        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        client.response = null;
//
        httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux " +
                "i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20061201 Firefox/2.0.0.6 (Ubuntu-feisty)");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xml," +
                "application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        try {
            if(nvps != null)
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.ISO_8859_1));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("HTTPHelp : UnsupportedEncodingException : "+e);
        }
        //httpPost.setEntity(tmp);

        try {
            client.response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPService : ClientProtocolException : "+e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPService : IOException : "+e);
            return null;
        } 

        cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore();
        return client;
    }
}
```

My websiteclient:

```
public DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
public HttpResponse response = null;

public WebsiteClient(ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager)
{
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params);
}
```

I must be doing something wrong with cookies, or should not use the same Httpget/Httppost or so. Hopefully I'll be able to solve this with a clear mind again tomorrow.

Ideas and input is appreciated!

Comment: We could take a better look if you posted your code. Hurry home =)

Comment: I will do so when I can. I just started my working day hehe, but I just felt the urge to post my question already, so in like 7-8 hours from now, I'll be able to update my question. I have such a feeling that I might miss out on some context-management or anything. As I never did such before, I 'grabbed' info from all kinds of threads, which resulted in what I got now :)

Comment: Thanks for the code post. Could you add the permissions that you've defined in your manifest xml?

Comment: I already put that bit in the post between all the text, but just did a new update and included it over there. I barely could sleep last night, and before I can continue, a working day is awaiting me again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to solve this very awkward problem I had, and will post the solution below. I unfortunately do not know the exact cause, but it is a combination of things surely.

Instead of creating a DefaultHttpClient again each time with my connection manager, I have created only **1 DefaultHttpClient, which I reuse all the time**. Also, each time I do a post or get, I create **a new HTTPGet/HTTPPost**, instead of reusing/recreating it from an existing.

Final constructor for my websiteservice-class:

```
private WebsiteService()
{
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = httpclient.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
    manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,mgr.getSchemeRegistry());
    localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    cookies = new BasicCookieStore();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookies);
}
```

A simple 'GetPage' call looks like this now:

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

        if(cookies != null)
            httpClient.setCookieStore(cookies);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            client.response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,localContext);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPService : ClientProtocolException : "+e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPService : IOException : "+e);
            return null;
        }
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think I can even leave out the setCookies bit. The cookies is in my situation a private declared CookieStore, which I fill after a post.

The last part which was annoying, is that upon rotating, it recreates the activity. To solve this, I extended the class which extends 'Application'. In this class, I put a list of my objects. In my 'OnCreate', I check if the list of objects exists, and use that list if available. Upon logging off, or refreshing, I recreate that list. The trick was just these few lines: (I left out the piece I added in the 'extends Application' class):

```
    if(((ApplicationInstance)getApplication()).getProfile() == null)
        this.initProfileItems();
    else
    {
        this.ProfileItems =((ApplicationInstance)getApplication()).getProfile(); 
        this.initListView();
    }
```

ApplicationInstance is my class which extends Application. My 'initList' processes the objects. My initProfileItems does an actual data get :-)

Hope I saved someone a headache :), and thanks for your time, @androidnoob!

Comment: I guess the root of the problem is largely due to the creation of DefaultHttpClient. Still unsure of this though, but very interesting. Glad that you've found a solution!

Comment: I think you are absolutely right androidnoob! I still had some issues with rotation things after all. I solved this with threads and info from the internet (mainly stack overflow ;) ).

Comment: Screen orientation is one of the things that you should take note of when dealing with HTTP, because the activity reloads by default each time the orientation changes. So take note of that and everything will be fine =)

Comment: Indeed, it's very awkward I found out. My next 'issue' is that when you haven't used the app for like half a day, and try to refresh the page, the cookies/login or so have expired and I get into an endless thread haha, but I'll manage, I think :)